# I like the way they Design/Architecture it but how do I implement this

Tags: architecture

**Summary:**

I have different components on homepage and each components shows some promotion to the user.

I have Cart as one Component and depending upon content of the cart promotion are show. 
I have to track user online activities and send that information to Omniture for Report Generation.

Now my components are loaded asynchronously basically are loaded when AjaxRequest is fired up and so there is not fix pattern or rather information on when components will appear on the webpages. Now in order to pass information to Omniture I need to call track function on `$(document).(ready)` and append information for each components(7 parameters are required by Omniture for each component).

So in the `init:config` function of each component am calling Omniture and passing paramters but now *`no. of Omniture calls is directly proportional to no. of Components on the webpage`* but this is not acceptable as each call to Omniture is very ***expensive***.

Now I am looking for a way where in I can club the information about 7 parameters and than make one Call to Omniture wherein I pass those information.

Points to  note is that I do not know when the components are loaded and so there is no pre-defined time or no. of components that would be loaded.

The thing is am calling track function when document is ready but components are loaded after call to Omniture has been made and so my question is

***Q: How can I collect the information for all the components and than just make one call to Omniture to send those information ?***

As mentioned, I do not know when the components are loaded as they are done on the Ajax Request.

Hope I am able to explain my challenge and would appreciate if some one can provide from ***Design/Architect*** Solutions for the Challenge.

Comment: Is this question clear ?

Comment: i think so. i don't have an answer yet; still thinking about it. Mind if i edit your post to include a couple of web analytics tags?

Comment: No. Please update my question to add Web Analytics Tag.

Comment: the question is clear enough I guess but the title has no information at all

Comment: Feel free to format title properly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't go directly to Omniture; go to a "middleman" which fetches the data.

I've never even heard of Omniture, but it sounds like senarios where your UI is going straight to the data layer - in which case you need a business logic layer in between.  That's the principle, anyway.

1. Create a layer of logic that handles all communication between the UI and Omniture.
2. The first UI call hits the logic layer / controller, e.g: Logic.GetPromotion()
3. When that happens have the logic call omniture -  get it do one batch call that gets all the data, much as you've descibed.
4. Pass the requested data (Logic.GetPromotion()) to whomever called it.
5. When the other calls hot the logic layer, it pulls that data out of the information it's just received - not from omniture.

Basically it's the [Lazy-Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) pattern; with the various concerns seperated - I'm not sure if I'd call it MVC - just properly structured (?).

One potential gotcha with this approach is that your calls are async - the logic controller might get a second call while it's still waiting for the results to come back from the first.  I haven't done anything along these lines myself, but there are plenty of multi-threading / concurrency type [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) out there that will help.

Comment: Try using an Http Proxy to see the requests going back and forth between the UI and Omniture; that might give you some insights as to what you need to do.  If Omniture is responsible for making the UI components that make all the expensive calls then I don't think there's much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all components make AJAX call at the page load time and gets loaded asynchronously.

Consider there are N number of components that are loaded. Hence there will be N number of AJAX calls made to the server.

With current implementation, on successful load of each component, call to Omniture is made.

Most browsers allow around maximum 2-5 active connections to the server. So above N calls will be executed at 2-5 concurrent calls at a time and will not gaurantee the order in with this calls complete.

We need to have a mechanisim to intercept AJAX calls to load a component, so then we can maintain list of this calls that are in progress and list of calls that are completed.

Once count of list of calls in progress is zero, all components have been loaded and we have info of each loaded component in list of completed AJAX calls.

Using list of info of each loaded component, make a single call to Omniture if it has required API. If Omniture, does not have API for bulk call, make a call to intermediate facade on server which will iteratively make a call to Omniture.

.

```
Have an API that will be used by components to make AJAX calls
Each time AJAX request is made for a component to load [new Ajax.Request(...)], 
    API adds component request info entry to requestInProgressList
Each time AJAX request is for a component is complete (function onComplete(...) callback), 
    API moves component request info entry from requestInProgressList to requestCompleteList
    IF requestInProgressList.count == 0 // No more pending requests
    THEN
        From requestCompleteList, collect the information for all the components into variable dataOmniture
        Clear requestCompleteList
        Make a call to Omniture to send dataOmniture information
    END
```

Comment: @JC: This is an algorithm, it won't compile. You need to implement it in JavaScript for it to run.

Comment: @Rachel: I updated solution with more info. Hope this is more verbose.